# How do I randomly pick an item from one of the lists inside a dictionary, and also get the key for the list?

Tags: python, list, random, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists:

```
lists=dict(animals=["dog","cat","shark"],
           things=["desk","chair","pencil"],
           food=["spaghetti","ice-cream","potatoes"])
```

How can I get Python to randomly pick an item from one of the lists and tell me what list it was in? Or how do I pick a key from the dictionary and then a value from the list corresponding to that key?

For example:

```
 
dog - from animals
potatoes - from food
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`random.choice`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice) picks a random item from a sequence:

```
import random
```

Select the key to draw from your `dict`, which you've named `lists`:

```
which_list = random.choice(lists.keys())
```

Then, use that key to get a `list` from the `dict`:

```
item = random.choice(lists[which_list])
```

If you need equal weighting:

```
import random

which_list, item = random.choice([(name, value) 
                                     for name, values in lists.iteritems() 
                                         for value in values])
```

Comment: thank you! worked perfectly!
I had already done the first part, but thought it wouldn't be able to do the second because it would render the which_list part a different list, dissociating it from its items!

Answer (score 3):

Two approaches I can think of right away:

- pick a list name (key) first, then pick an entry from it -- you'll just have to be careful if the lists have different lengths, if you want an uniform distribution
- flatten the dict of lists into one list of `('list-name','value')` pairs (easier to get the uniform distribution right no matter how many entries there are per list, but requires more memory)

One way to do the former:

```
from itertools import chain
import random
weight_choices = list(chain(*([name] * len(values) for (name, values) in lists.iteritems()))) # generate a list of the form ("animals", "animals", "animals", ...)
list_name = random.choice(weight_choice) # The list it's chosen from...
chosen_item = random.choice(lists[list_name]) # and the item itself
```

(and if you don't care about getting an uniform distribution between lists:)

```
import random
list_name = random.choice(lists.keys())
chosen_item = random.choice(lists[list_name])
```

... and the latter method:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat
all_items = list(chain(*((zip(repeat(name), values) for (name, values) in lists.iteritems()))))
list_name, chosen_item = random.choice(all_items)
```

and a less `itertools` way for the latter:

```
all_items = []
for name, values in lists.iteritems():
  for value in values:
    all_items.append((name, value))
list_name, chosen_item = random.choice(all_items)
```

Comment: He says in his question "Or rather, to pick a key from the dictionary and then a value from inside that chosen key. Like: dog - from animals, potatoes - from food" so think all this is way more complex than necessary.

Comment: Sure, but I didn't want to assume that was his production data. For all I know, there could be 800 lists with 753 items each. (In which case neither of my solutions is very optimal, anyway...)

Comment: I don't see the problem with the naive approach with the dataset you propose? I also added a simple "equal-weight" solution to my answer, if the lists are uneven lengths.

Comment: thanks, but the other one is way simpler, and the lists are no longer than 50 items each... so there is no need for all that code!

Comment: flattening is the only way to ensure there is equal probability of choosing key,value pair